# Do jQuery empty() and remove() functions execute asynchronously?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

Do `jQuery.fn.empty()` and `remove()` functions execute asynchronously? I can't find an answer to this question anywhere in the jQuery documentation.

Answer (score 9):

They're both synchronous. You can look at [the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L76) for the actual implementation:

```
remove: function( selector, keepData ) {
    var elem,
        elems = selector ? jQuery.filter( selector, this ) : this,
        i = 0;

    for ( ; (elem = elems[i]) != null; i++ ) {
        if ( !keepData && elem.nodeType === 1 ) {
            jQuery.cleanData( getAll( elem ) );
        }

        if ( elem.parentNode ) {
            if ( keepData && jQuery.contains( elem.ownerDocument, elem ) ) {
                setGlobalEval( getAll( elem, "script" ) );
            }
            elem.parentNode.removeChild( elem );
        }
    }

    return this;
},

empty: function() {
    var elem,
        i = 0;

    for ( ; (elem = this[i]) != null; i++ ) {
        if ( elem.nodeType === 1 ) {

            // Prevent memory leaks
            jQuery.cleanData( getAll( elem, false ) );

            // Remove any remaining nodes
            elem.textContent = "";
        }
    }

    return this;
},
```

You can ignore the `keepData` and `cleanData` stuff, so all you're left with is a loop and a call to a native DOM method or a DOM object property modification. Those are both synchronous.

Answer (score 2):

No, they are chainable methods so they'll finish before returning the original jQuery object.

Comment: Small nitpick, but the fact that they're chainable doesn't really mean they're synchronous. As a counterexample, take a look at the animation methods-- those are chainable but every animation is necessarily asynchronous. In that case, jQuery uses a function queue in the background to schedule the next animation after the first is completed.

Answer (score 1):

They are synchronous, if there is a reason for you to want them to be asynchronous (Wait until the current execution path finishes, and then empty the queue sometime), you can do:

```
// Empty asynchronously
setTimeout(function(){
    $('...').empty();
}, 0);
```